# How to write this elegantly in Python?

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I am trying to write this loop in Python but get confused. Basically I have a starting angle 90 that I want to use a range of -90 to 90, iterating 10 times. After the loop is done, I want to divide the angle by half and repeat the process of using -45 to 45, by 10 iterations, etc.

The end values must be included, so 90 is the last value for the first loop, then 45 is the last value for the second loops, etc.

How can I write this elegantly and efficiently in Python?

```
startAngle = 90
for i in range(5):
    for x in range(10):
        print values from -startAngle to startAngle (startAngle included)
    startAngle = startAngle / 2
```

Comment: Can you show some psuedocode for what you want to do, or at least describe the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Seems like an obvious case for recursion.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def angles(x):
    return [ i * x / 5 - x for i in xrange(11)]
```

`angles(90)` returns `[-90, -72, -54, -36, -18, 0, 18, 36, 54, 72, 90]`

`angles(45)` returns `[-45, -36, -27, -18, -9, 0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45]`

You can now iterate over the return value, it is a list.

There are ten steps in my `angles` method returning eleven values.

If you want another number of steps:

```
def angles(angle, steps):
    return [ i * angle * 2 / (steps - 1) - angle for i in xrange(steps)]
```

`angles(90, 5)` returns `[-90, -45, 0, 45, 90]`

Comment: Thanks this does what I want. Btw why is def better than lambda?

Comment: @JoanVenge: `def x(...)` is identical to `x = lambda(...)`. Stylistically, I believe it's better to define all functions using `def` for code readability. `lambda`'s main purpose is for anonymous functions, as in `sorted(some_list, key=lambda x: ...do something...)`

Comment: For maximum laziness, this should return a generator expression instead of a list.

Comment: @JoanVenge: Also, `def funct(...` may be modified more easily than the lambda (later, in future development) as lambda cannot use more complex control structures inside its body.

Answer (score 4):

Your trouble seems to be translating:

```
print values from -startAngle to startAngle (startAngle included)
```

into Python. `range` can handle this trivially:

```
print(list(range(-startAngle, startAngle+1)))
```

Except you seem to want exactly ten values - this gives `2*startAngle+1` values (`range(-a, a)` has 2a values, and this has one more) and putting in your example code will print out all of those ten times.

A properly-chosen `step` argument to `range` can guarantee that it will give `numvalues` elements - you want the step as the number of values in the un-`step`ed range divided by the number of values you want, rounding up because `range` wants integers:

```
print(list(range(-startAngle, startAngle+1, math.ceil((2*startangle+1)/numvalues))
```

So, numvalues=10 and startAngle=45 gives you:

```
list(range(-45, 46, math.ceil((2*45+1)/10)))
[-45, -35, -25, -15, -5, 5, 15, 25, 35, 45]
```

Note that I'm assuming you're using Python 3. In Python 2, you can do:

```
from __future__ import division
```

or set `numvalues` to `10.`, do `range(...)` instead of `list(range(...))`, and do `int(ceil(...))` instead of `ceil(...)` to the same effect.

---

Another way, which also works properly if you need to handle floats, is to use [numpy.linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html?highlight=linspace#numpy.linspace) - it takes a `num` argument instead of a `step`, and by default includes its endpoint - so,

```
numpy.linspace(-startAngle, startAngle, num=10)
```

Will give you what you want directly.

Comment: I was gonna use the startANgle+1 trick but would it not cause extra iterations when the angle iteration gets below 1?

Comment: +1 Pushing the step to `range` is pretty nice, saving computation time.

Comment: @JoanVenge Don't understand your question :)

Comment: Thanks but where does the 2*45 come from? I assume it's hard to modify to make it 10 elements? UVed, neat trick, just wondering.

Comment: @JoanVenge if you need to handle the case where `0 < startAngle < 1`, use `arange` from Numpy ( http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#arange ) - it has exactly the same signature (well, except it has one more optional one that you don't care about for this), but handles floats the way you would expect (well, roughly. There's always the risk of running into representation and overflow, but that will haunt *any* solution).

Comment: @JoanVenge the step is calculated to give whatever number of values you want - it is based on `2*startAngle` because that is the number of elements in `range(-startAngle, startAngle+1)` (or, really, one less than it because of 0). Setting `numvalues` to the number of elements you want will cause the step `2*startAngle//(numvalues-1)` to be the right one for giving you `numvalues` elements in the range (as long as you're crossing zero; it'll be off by one otherwise).

Comment: @JoanVenge I've updated my answer to make this calculation clearer, as well as where it comes from (note that I was wrong about the rationale in my last comment - its because of the endpoint rather than 0 - and this understanding leads to a less strange formula).

Answer (score -2):

```
 def ang_rec(angel):
     for i in range(10):
         if i == 9: ang_rec(angel/2)
         print "do something another"
```

Comment: It doesn't produce any output (besides printing "do something another" to `stdout`). Also, I wouldn't call it "pythonic".

Comment: I just never thought before that stackoverflow is a center of solutions school homework. I point to recursion concept, but I dont want to do author's homework.

Comment: I agree with you about not answering homework questions explicitly, but 1) The point of answering homework question is to increase the OP's understanding of a concept -- this answer is confusing and does not include any sort of explanation and 2) You're making the assumption that this is homework, and that the OP -- who has a reputation of 14,400 -- is a student.

Comment: @Denis: I am not a student, and if you look at the question I am looking for an elegant solution in Python, not a language I am very experienced.

Comment: Also this method is far from elegant. I use 2 for loops, not use an if check to halve the value. Btw it's angle not "angel". just FYI.